# Password retry limit shows user locked but error updating user store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2 ver5.0, we have a password retry limit set to 5 attempts. After that it shows the user as locked. However it does not update the accountLocked attribute in the DB. But whenever I come back to that user it still shows as locked so it is storing the value somewhere (maybe in a cookie). If I lock the user manually, all works fine. I downloaded the source and found where half of the error message is thrown, but no luck finding the second part as shown here:

ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin} -  **System error while Authenticating/Authorizing User** :Error 
while saving user store data for user

Anyone know where the logon attempt counter is located in source and where the locking mechanism is called?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What is your primary user store ? embaded LDAP or any JDBC user store ?

Comment: The primary store is JDBC (SQL Server). Additional info: I installed IS on local PC and tested and it works correctly relative to the issue at hand. After investigation, the local version is only patched through patch0008 where as the produciton version has an addition 8 patches applied. My current reasoning is that one of the subsequent patches broke this feature.

Comment: Most probably this issue will be resolved if you can install service pack 1. You can test this scenario with test environment with service pack1.

Comment: Make sure whether these claims are existing in the claim list`http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountLocked
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/unlockTime
http://wso2.org/claims/identity/failedLoginAttempts` or not.